# Unexpected reaching maximal recursion depth in Python

Tags: python, recursion, stack, depth, recurrence

```
N=3
pre_calc=["-1" for i in range (N+2)]
def calc(i) :
    if(pre_calc[i] =="-1"):
        if i==0:
             pre_calc[i] ="a[0]"
        elif i==N+1:
            pre_calc[i]= "a[N+1]"
        else:
            pre_calc[i] ="("+str(calc(i-1))+"+"+str(calc(i+1))+")/2-c["+str(i)+"]"
    return pre_calc[i] ;
ans=calc(1)
print (ans)
```

I am solving recurrence a[i] =(a[i-1]+a[i+1])/2-c[i], where c[i], a[0] and a[N+1].  That is problem 1047 on Timus. 
So,  to understand that recurrence I decided to write a program that would output an expression of a[1] in terms of a[0],a[N+1] and c[i].
I did. 
Bit it absolutely doesn't works! 
I want to know why stack depth limit is exceed even if N is two.

Answer (score 1):

`calc(1)` calls `calc(2)` (i + 1 call), which calls `calc(1)` (i - 1 call), which calls `calc(2)`, which calls `calc(1)`, which calls `calc(2)` ...

Comment: Why it is not that way? N=2. calc(1)=calc(0)+calc(2)=a[0]+(calc(1)+calc(3)) /2-c[1]=a[0]+(calc(0)+calc(2)+a[3])/2-c[1]=a[0]+(a[0]+(calc(1)+a[3])/2-c[1]+a[3])/2-c[1]...Oh, nice!!!  I understood now,  where the problem lies.  Thanks.

Comment: @NikitaMahilewets no problem, if the question is answered please consider accepting the answer by selecting the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score -1):

Recursive methods,and funcs are very very dangerous for the program if you rewrite calc function as unrecursive style, you get rid of this problem.

don't never use recursive methods when you have not to use

Edith:

if you are sure the max depth of func and the max depth value isn't very high (lower than depth limit), of course you can use it func. but if you don't know max depth, don't use it because it func can kill your program.

for example **recursive factorial** func too dangerous because max depth of this func can higher than dept limit.

Comment: Electricity is very dangerous. Don't ever use it if you don't have to. Use candles.

Comment: Yes. Electricity can kill human with high voltage and recursive methods can kill the program with stackoverflow.